# How are things embedded inside of a browser?

Tags: java, linux, flash, firefox, ubuntu

Adobe embedded flash and Oracle embedded Java. How does one go about embedding external programs inside a browser. I'm on Linux BTW.

Answer (score 3):

You write something called a *browser plug-in*, which is done via the [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI), and then you get users to install it (or you get system makers to pre-install it).